# How to add .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 assemblies to FxCop code analysis?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, fxcop, assembly-resolution

I want to analyze a solution that contains projects targeting .NET 3.5 SP1 and some other projects targeting .NET 4 with some dependencies to .NET 3.5 libraries.

When I try to add both assemblies, one for .NET 3.5 and another for .NET 4, FxCop throws an exception:

```
AssemblyLoadException
Conflicting target platforms
'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' vs
'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Is there any way to tell FxCop to only use version 4.0.0.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell FxCop to only use version 4.0.0.0?

No, I don't think there is - you will need one FxCop project for the projects targeting .NET 3.5, and another for those targeting .NET 4.0.